# Which response goes with which request?

Tags: python, openerp-7, asyncore, urllib3

I'm using `Python` with `OpenERP 7`.
I fire requests to partners using `urllib3`. Some of these requests may be asynchronous.
So I've built a little `asyncore` server to wait for responses.
But the thing is, the server cannot know which response goes with which request.

In the content of my request, I have a tag named *TransactionID*.
So far, I tried to link responses with requests using this *TransactionID*.
But the responses are not the same from one partner to another.
So, what I've done is create a list of possible *TransactionID tag structures*.

This method works, but it's so ugly.
I was hopping for a better, cleaner solution, if someone knows how to achieve that.

Thanks !

**Edit:**

I've made a mistake by calling it asynchronous I think.
The partner gives a synchronous response. But it's just to confirm that my request is ok.
Later, the partner will send me a response on a specific url:port on my server. This is the response I'm talking about. Sorry if I've not given enough details.

Comment: I will update my question.

Comment: please share your code so that we make it Pretty :) . it will be easy to draw solution

Comment: My code is a mess 800 lines long, with other stuff in it to make it more "generic". This code grabs a xml tree structure defined by some user, grabs some data from the same database, then throw a request out of it. Besides, there's an asyncore server that listen to a specific port, then put the response back to a handler function.     So I think that if I post it it will be a pain for both of us :/